# Get columns from MySQL and display in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I`ve created table where i want to store some page content

```
CREATE TABLE `option` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `parametr` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `value` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `status` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

For example filled with this parametrs

```
id  parametr      value                    status
1   title         test                     active
2   subtitle      subtest                  active
3   category      machine                  active
4   description   detailed_description     active
```

Then i want to display only choosen id in different parts of page.
Currently i'm doing this as below, however it`s not allowed me to display multiple parametrs in different places without starting placing the same code in new place where i want it ( test,subtest,detailed_description and somewhere machine)

```
<div class="title-section">
    <?php 
     $sel_option = "SELECT value FROM option WHERE status = 'active' AND id = '1' ";
     $run_option = mysqli_query($connect,$sel_option);
     while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_option)) {
     echo '<h3>'.$rows['value'].'</h3>';}
     ?>
```

How to do it with different way ?

Comment: You could put the whole SQL part in a function then in each HTML part just pass the function the `id` and connection. `get_sql_data($connect, $id);`

Comment: Not sure what is the result you expect? you need Id=1 you ask for it. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I am not pretty sure what you need exactly, but if I understood well, you don't want to run the query every time you need to show a title, subtitle, category or description, right?

Try it:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <p><h3 id="title">Ronaldo</h3></p>
        <p><h3 id="subtitle">The Brazilian Soccer Player Legend</h3></p>
        <p><h3 id="category">Soccer</h3></p>
        <p><h3 id="description">Ronaldo Luís Nazário de Lima commonly known as Ronaldo.</h3></p>

        <script type="text/javascript">
    <?php 
        $sel_option = "SELECT parametr, value FROM option WHERE status = 'active'";
        $run_option = mysqli_query($connect,$sel_option);
        while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_option)) {
            echo 'var a = document.getElementById("'.$rows['parametr'].'");';
            echo 'a.innerHTML = "'.$rows['value'].'";';
        }
    ?>
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I want to replace Ronaldo with one value from database
I want to replace The Brazilian Soccer Player Legend with one value from database, etc

Comment: jagrok, that's what the script above is suppose to do. Did you try it? Just to explain better: for each `<h3>`, I added an attribute `id` which must have the same name than the column `parametr`. Then, I created a mix of JavaScript and PHP. The JavaScript code changes the value of each `<h3>` depending of their `ID` while the PHP code is suppose to get the database parametr and value columns to fulfill the JS code. NOTE: in this example, it is important to mention that the `<script>` element should be right before the `</html>` because the JavaScript may not recognize the <h3>'s ID.

Comment: Yes i try it,but it`s not replacing this words.
However i dont want to typically replace Ronaldo, i just want to get "Ronaldo" from database but not from rows but from column.

The simple way is to create separate table for this option, but i would like to know how to do it with different method.